# Jquery JSON FORMAT ERROR

Tags: json, jquery

```
{"simpleSearchResult" :
 { 
  "facultydetail":
     [
      {"comboValue":"FACULTY"},
      {"facultyDetail":
          [
           "Android",
           "Android profile",
           "balaguru",
           "Ulsoor",
           "balaguru@savinirs.com",
           "Bangalore",
           "Karnataka",
           "India",
           "83",
           "3 years of teaching experiance",
           "INR",
           "10000.0",
           "40",
           "20000.0"
          ]
      },
      {"NunberOfPages":"1"},
      {"CurrentPage":"1"},
      {"SkillIds":"an"},
      {"cityId":"ba"},
      {"DisplayCboValue":"STUDENT"},
      {"Limit":"0"},
      {"PageComboVal":"10"},
      {"discipline":"Languages"}
     ]
 }
}
```

This is my JSON string from my action class i am returning this to jQuery ajax call but that is always going to error block, gving parse error any one please help me to fix this issue

Comment: The JSON is valid - what is the rest of your code that is erroring?

Comment: Reformat your post, get rid of caps-locking and let's see what you're saying. Also add the error output.

Comment: checked in this service http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple JSON validators available online which can pinpoint the problem with JSON formatting. I used http://www.jsonlint.com/ and it appears that your JSON is valid. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for your reply JSON Validator is telling my json string is a valid json, but in my jqury   ajax response its always going to error block, and giving parsing error.and i changed my format to this  {"simpleSearchResult" : [{"comboValue":"FACULTY","facultyDetail":["Android","Android Profile","bala","Ulsoor","balaguru@savinirs.com","Bangalore","Karnataka","India","85","3 years","INR","10000.0","45","aa","20000.0"],"NunberOfPages":"1","CurrentPage":"1","SkillIds":"an","cityId":"ba","DisplayCboValue":"STUDENT","Limit":"0","PageComboVal":"10","discipline":"Languages"}] } then its working fine